# How to deform/modify image with BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I don't know how can i deform image like this with BufferedImage . Can someone help me ?
I am absolutely desperate. thanks for all tips. Sorry for my English.

[image]

```
                |
                |
               \ /  
                V
```

[image]

Comment: Thx I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a easy task you have to make an algorithm to calculate per pixel in the new BufferedImage where the Pixel from the last BufferedImage will be taken.

You can use getARGB and setARGB for this. Also make sure that you catch the possibility that one of the pixels in your new image doesn't point to a pixel in the old image.

This isn't a fast process so if you have the possibility to save it and reuse it instead of remutating it every time that would save you a lot of cpu work.

Comment: Thx for you answer, but I wanted the part with the calculate. Never mind i found the solution :)